# Bug golang on goroutines | Reading and writing in Excel

Tags: goland

I have a big problem with a go script and despite my research I'm stuck..
I make a script that reads Excel sheets or other Excel sheets are filled in, and so for each of these sheets I retrieve the information then write it in an Excel file that I create. I have a version that works but as soon as I change the Excel package it doesn't work.

I get error messages like this:

```golang
goroutine 20151 [chan send]:
FilesDIR/pkg.CompilerFicheAppuiFt.func1()
        C:/Users/doria/go/src/FilesDIR/pkg/compiler.go:130 +0x8c
created by FilesDIR/pkg.CompilerFicheAppuiFt
        C:/Users/doria/go/src/FilesDIR/pkg/compiler.go:126 +0xa77

goroutine 20152 [chan send]:
FilesDIR/pkg.CompilerFicheAppuiFt.func1()
        C:/Users/doria/go/src/FilesDIR/pkg/compiler.go:130 +0x8c
created by FilesDIR/pkg.CompilerFicheAppuiFt
        C:/Users/doria/go/src/FilesDIR/pkg/compiler.go:126 +0xa77

goroutine 20153 [chan send]:
FilesDIR/pkg.CompilerFicheAppuiFt.func1()
        C:/Users/doria/go/src/FilesDIR/pkg/compiler.go:130 +0x8c
created by FilesDIR/pkg.CompilerFicheAppuiFt
        C:/Users/doria/go/src/FilesDIR/pkg/compiler.go:126 +0xa77

goroutine 20154 [chan send]:
FilesDIR/pkg.CompilerFicheAppuiFt.func1()
        C:/Users/doria/go/src/FilesDIR/pkg/compiler.go:130 +0x8c
created by FilesDIR/pkg.CompilerFicheAppuiFt
        C:/Users/doria/go/src/FilesDIR/pkg/compiler.go:126 +0xa77

goroutine 20155 [chan send]:
FilesDIR/pkg.CompilerFicheAppuiFt.func1()
        C:/Users/doria/go/src/FilesDIR/pkg/compiler.go:130 +0x8c
created by FilesDIR/pkg.CompilerFicheAppuiFt
        C:/Users/doria/go/src/FilesDIR/pkg/compiler.go:126 +0xa77
```

The problem is that I need to change the package because I need to get the Cell Styles and currently I can't do it. Does anyone have any idea what the problem is please? thanks in advance.

the code that works:

```golang
package pkg

import (
    "FilesDIR/display"
    "FilesDIR/globals"
    "FilesDIR/loger"
    "FilesDIR/task"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize"
    "github.com/tealeg/xlsx"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type compilData struct {
    Path string
    Id   int
}

var (
    wg   sync.WaitGroup
    jobs = make(chan compilData)
    Wb   = &excelize.File{}
    Id   int
)

//...
// ACTIONS:
func ClsTempFiles() {
    _ = os.RemoveAll(globals.FolderLogs)
    _ = os.RemoveAll(globals.FolderDumps)
    _ = os.RemoveAll(globals.FolderExports)
}

func CompilerFicheAppuiFt(path string) {
    path = "C:\\Users\\doria\\FilesDIR\\Nouveau dossier"

    loger.BlankDateln(display.DrawInitCompiler())
    time.Sleep(800 * time.Millisecond)

    loger.Blankln(display.DrawRunCompiler())

    Id = 1

    Wb = excelize.NewFile()
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "A1", "Chemin de la fiche")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "B1", "Adresse")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "C1", "Ville")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "D1", "Num appui")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "E1", "Type appui")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "F1", "Type_n_app")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "G1", "Nature TVX")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "H1", "Etiquette jaune")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "I1", "Effort avant ajout câble")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "J1", "Effort après ajout câble")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "K1", "Effort nouveau appui")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "L1", "Latitude")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "M1", "Longitude")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "N1", "Opérateur")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "O1", "Appui utilisable en l'état")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "P1", "Environnement")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "Q1", "Commentaire appui")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "R1", "Commentaire global")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "S1", "Proxi ENEDIS")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "T1", "id_metier_")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "U1", "Date")
    _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "V1", "PB")

    for w := 1; w <= 10; w++ {
        go workerFicheAppuiFt()
    }

    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path)
    if err != nil {
        loger.Crashln(fmt.Sprintf("Crash with this path: %s", path))
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        if !file.IsDir() && !strings.Contains(file.Name(), "__COMPILATION__") {

            excelFile := filepath.Join(path, file.Name())
            f, err := xlsx.OpenFile(excelFile)
            if err != nil {
                loger.Errorln(fmt.Sprintf("Crash with this files: %s", excelFile))
                continue
            }

            sht := f.Sheets[0]

            maxRow := sht.MaxRow

            for i := 0; i < maxRow; i++ {
                row, err := sht.Row(i)
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }

                go func() {
                    wg.Add(1)
                    Id++

                    jobs <- compilData{
                        Path: row.GetCell(3).String(),
                        Id:   Id,
                    }
                }()
            }
        }
    }

    wg.Wait()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    loger.BlankDateln(display.DrawEndCompiler())

    loger.BlankDateln(fmt.Sprintf("Nombre de fiches compilées : %v", Id-1))
    time.Sleep(800 * time.Millisecond)

    if err := Wb.SaveAs(filepath.Join(path, fmt.Sprintf("__COMPILATION__%v.xlsx", time.Now().Format("20060102150405")))); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    loger.Blankln(display.DrawSaveExcel())
    fmt.Println()
    time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
}

//...
//WORKER:
func workerFicheAppuiFt() {
    for job := range jobs {
        loger.BlankDateln(fmt.Sprintf("N°%v | Files: %s", job.Id, filepath.Base(job.Path)))

        excelFile := job.Path
        f, err := excelize.OpenFile(excelFile)
        if err != nil {
            loger.Errorln(fmt.Sprintf("Crash with this files: %s", filepath.Base(excelFile)))
            wg.Done()
            continue
        }

        sht := f.GetSheetName(f.GetActiveSheetIndex())

        adresse, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "D5")
        ville, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "D4")
        numAppui, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "D3")
        type1, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "C26")
        typeNApp, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "M52")
        natureTvx, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "M53")

        etiquetteJaune, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "U12")
        switch task.StrToLower(etiquetteJaune) {
        case "oui":
            etiquetteJaune = "non"
        case "non":
            etiquetteJaune = "oui"
        }

        effort1, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "S26")
        effort2, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "U26")
        effort3, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "W26")

        lat, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "P5")
        lon, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "P6")
        operateur, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "J3")
        utilisableEnEtat, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "W12")
        environnement, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "W52")
        commentaireEtatAppui, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "F13")
        commentaireGlobal, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "A55")
        proxiEnedis, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "W53")

        insee, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "V4")
        idMetier := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", numAppui, insee)

        date, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "T1")
        pb, _ := f.GetCellValue(sht, "N18")

        // insert value
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("A%v", job.Id), job.Path)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("B%v", job.Id), adresse)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("C%v", job.Id), ville)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("D%v", job.Id), numAppui)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("E%v", job.Id), type1)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("F%v", job.Id), typeNApp)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("G%v", job.Id), natureTvx)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("H%v", job.Id), etiquetteJaune)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("I%v", job.Id), effort1)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("J%v", job.Id), effort2)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("K%v", job.Id), effort3)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("L%v", job.Id), lat)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("M%v", job.Id), lon)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("N%v", job.Id), operateur)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("O%v", job.Id), utilisableEnEtat)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("P%v", job.Id), environnement)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("Q%v", job.Id), commentaireEtatAppui)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("R%v", job.Id), commentaireGlobal)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("S%v", job.Id), proxiEnedis)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("T%v", job.Id), idMetier)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("U%v", job.Id), date)
        _ = Wb.SetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("V%v", job.Id), pb)

        err = f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            loger.Errorln(fmt.Sprintf("Crash with this files: %s", excelFile))
            continue
        }

        wg.Done()
    }
}
```

and the one that refuses:

```golang
package pkg

import (
    "FilesDIR/display"
    "FilesDIR/globals"
    "FilesDIR/loger"
    "FilesDIR/task"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/tealeg/xlsx"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type compilData struct {
    Path string
    Id   int
}

var (
    wg   sync.WaitGroup
    jobs = make(chan compilData)
    Wb   = &xlsx.File{}
    Sht  = &xlsx.Sheet{}
    Id   int
)

//...
// ACTIONS:
func ClsTempFiles() {
    _ = os.RemoveAll(globals.FolderLogs)
    _ = os.RemoveAll(globals.FolderDumps)
    _ = os.RemoveAll(globals.FolderExports)
}

func CompilerFicheAppuiFt(path string) {
    path = "C:\\Users\\doria\\FilesDIR\\Nouveau dossier"

    loger.BlankDateln(display.DrawInitCompiler())
    time.Sleep(800 * time.Millisecond)

    loger.Blankln(display.DrawRunCompiler())

    Id = 1

    Wb = xlsx.NewFile()
    Sht, _ = Wb.AddSheet("Sheet1")

    col0, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 0)
    col0.SetValue("Chemin de la fiche")
    col1, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 1)
    col1.SetValue("Adresse")
    col2, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 2)
    col2.SetValue("Ville")
    col3, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 3)
    col3.SetValue("Num appui")
    col4, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 4)
    col4.SetValue("Type appui")
    col5, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 5)
    col5.SetValue("Type_n_app")
    col6, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 6)
    col6.SetValue("Nature TVX")
    col7, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 7)
    col7.SetValue("Etiquette jaune")
    col8, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 8)
    col8.SetValue("Effort avant ajout câble")
    col9, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 9)
    col9.SetValue("Effort après ajout câble")
    col10, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 10)
    col10.SetValue("Effort nouveau appui")
    col11, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 11)
    col11.SetValue("Latitude")
    col12, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 12)
    col12.SetValue("Longitude")
    col13, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 13)
    col13.SetValue("Opérateur")
    col14, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 14)
    col14.SetValue("Appui utilisable en l'état")
    col15, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 15)
    col15.SetValue("Environnement")
    col16, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 16)
    col16.SetValue("Commentaire appui")
    col17, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 17)
    col17.SetValue("Commentaire global")
    col18, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 18)
    col18.SetValue("Proxi ENEDIS")
    col19, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 19)
    col19.SetValue("id_metier_")
    col20, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 20)
    col20.SetValue("Date")
    col21, _ := Sht.Cell(0, 21)
    col21.SetValue("PB")

    for w := 1; w <= 10; w++ {
        go workerFicheAppuiFt()
    }

    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path)
    if err != nil {
        loger.Crashln(fmt.Sprintf("Crash with this path: %s", path))
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        if !file.IsDir() && !strings.Contains(file.Name(), "__COMPILATION__") {

            excelFile := filepath.Join(path, file.Name())
            f, err := xlsx.OpenFile(excelFile)
            if err != nil {
                loger.Errorln(fmt.Sprintf("Crash with this files: %s", excelFile))
                continue
            }

            sht := f.Sheets[0]

            maxRow := sht.MaxRow

            for i := 0; i < maxRow; i++ {
                row, err := sht.Row(i)
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }

                go func() {
                    wg.Add(1)
                    Id++

                    jobs <- compilData{
                        Path: row.GetCell(3).String(),
                        Id:   Id,
                    }
                }()
            }
        }
    }

    wg.Wait()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    loger.BlankDateln(display.DrawEndCompiler())

    loger.BlankDateln(fmt.Sprintf("Nombre de fiches compilées : %v", Id-1))
    time.Sleep(800 * time.Millisecond)

    if err := Wb.Save(filepath.Join(path, fmt.Sprintf("__COMPILATION__%v.xlsx", time.Now().Format("20060102150405")))); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    loger.Blankln(display.DrawSaveExcel())
    fmt.Println()
    time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
}

//...
//WORKER:
func workerFicheAppuiFt() {
    for job := range jobs {
        loger.BlankDateln(fmt.Sprintf("N°%v | Files: %s", job.Id, filepath.Base(job.Path)))

        excelFile := job.Path
        f, err := xlsx.OpenFile(excelFile)
        if err != nil {
            loger.Errorln(fmt.Sprintf("Crash with this files: %s", filepath.Base(excelFile)))
            wg.Done()
            continue
        }

        sht := f.Sheets[0]

        adresse, _ := sht.Cell(4, 3)
        ville, _ := sht.Cell(3, 3)
        numAppui, _ := sht.Cell(2, 3)
        type1, _ := sht.Cell(25, 2)
        typeNApp, _ := sht.Cell(51, 12)
        natureTvx, _ := sht.Cell(52, 12)

        cellEtiquetteJaune, _ := sht.Cell(11, 20)
        etiquetteJaune := ""
        switch task.StrToLower(cellEtiquetteJaune.Value) {
        case "oui":
            etiquetteJaune = "non"
        case "non":
            etiquetteJaune = "oui"
        }

        effort1, _ := sht.Cell(25, 18)
        effort2, _ := sht.Cell(25, 20)
        effort3, _ := sht.Cell(25, 22)

        lat, _ := sht.Cell(4, 15)
        lon, _ := sht.Cell(5, 15)
        operateur, _ := sht.Cell(2, 9)
        utilisableEnEtat, _ := sht.Cell(11, 22)
        environnement, _ := sht.Cell(51, 22)
        commentaireEtatAppui, _ := sht.Cell(12, 5)
        commentaireGlobal, _ := sht.Cell(54, 0)
        proxiEnedis, _ := sht.Cell(52, 22)

        insee, _ := sht.Cell(3, 21)
        idMetier := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", numAppui.Value, insee.Value)
        date, _ := sht.Cell(0, 19)
        pb, _ := sht.Cell(17, 13)

        // insert value
        col0, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 0)
        col0.SetValue(job.Path)
        col1, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 1)
        col1.SetValue(adresse.Value)
        col2, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 2)
        col2.SetValue(ville.Value)
        col3, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 3)
        col3.SetValue(numAppui.Value)
        col4, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 4)
        col4.SetValue(type1.Value)
        col5, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 5)
        col5.SetValue(typeNApp.Value)
        col6, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 6)
        col6.SetValue(natureTvx.Value)
        col7, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 7)
        col7.SetValue(etiquetteJaune)
        col8, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 8)
        col8.SetValue(effort1.Value)
        col9, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 9)
        col9.SetValue(effort2.Value)
        col10, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 10)
        col10.SetValue(effort3.Value)
        col11, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 11)
        col11.SetValue(lat.Value)
        col12, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 12)
        col12.SetValue(lon.Value)
        col13, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 13)
        col13.SetValue(operateur.Value)
        col14, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 14)
        col14.SetValue(utilisableEnEtat.Value)
        col15, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 15)
        col15.SetValue(environnement.Value)
        col16, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 16)
        col16.SetValue(commentaireEtatAppui.Value)
        col17, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 17)
        col17.SetValue(commentaireGlobal.Value)
        col18, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 18)
        col18.SetValue(proxiEnedis.Value)
        col19, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 19)
        col19.SetValue(idMetier)
        col20, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 20)
        col20.SetValue(date.Value)
        col21, _ := Sht.Cell(job.Id, 21)
        col21.SetValue(pb.Value)

        wg.Done()
    }
}
```